# Why should I use a daemon instead of a cron job?

Tags: cron, daemon

I want to send messages to users at a specific time (like 15 minutes after each event that a user puts in). Users can schedule events for any time/any day. Why should I use a daemon instead of a cron job? What are the pros and crons for cron job vs daemon?

Comment: Who said you were to use a daemon?

Comment: Based on what you say, you probably *should* use cron. The problem you describe is exactly the one cron is supposed to solve. The only reason you might want to roll your own daemon would be if you had so many of these events scheduled that the process-management overhead for the cron jobs might become a problem. Otherwise, rolling your own daemon would be an exercise in wheel-reinvention.

Comment: BTW: cron *is* a daemon. So you end up with a daemon either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A daemon is for process that you wish to be constantly running. A wsgi server for example where incoming communications could come at anytime. A cron job is for batch jobs that should occur with some regular frequency.

This sounds like a cron job. You could set up a timer or a while loop to constantly run and dispatch messages every hour(what ever time you choose). however it is added complexity you do not need. make a script that runs in batch and call it at the regular interval you need.